# No Json deserializer found for type java.util.Date

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm working on the following lines of code.

```
val list = Car.getNames()
Ok(Json.toJson(list))
```

I got the following errors....

> [error] my_app/app/models/Car.scala:51: No Json deserializer found for type java.util.Date. Try to implement an implicit Reads or Format for this type.

`Car` has `java.util.date` object as one of parameters and I implemented the *Reads* and *Writes* to support the `java.util.date` object since `import play.api.libs.json.*` does not support it.

Would you point my mistakes?

```
implicit object CarFormat extends Format[Car] {

    def reads(json: JsValue): Car = Car(
      (json \ "id").as[Long],
      (json \ "height").as[Double],
      (json \ "weight").as[Double],
      (json \ "date").asOpt[java.util.Date]
    )   

    def writes(car: Car) = 
        JsObject(
            Seq(
                "id" -> JsString(car.id.toString),
                "height" -> JsString(car.height.toString),
                "weight" -> JsString(car.weight.toString),
                "date" -> JsString(car.date.toString)
            )   
        )   
}
```

Comment: I suggest you do not use java.util.Date - use a better date class such as Joda Date Time. Here is a Scala wrapper for https://github.com/jorgeortiz85/scala-time

Comment: I'm sorry about late response and I got a exact result what I want from your comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 11):

You only defined `Format` for `Car` but it requires a `Format` for `java.util.Date`. Try this:

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Car(id:Long, height:Double, weight:Double, date:Option[java.util.Date])

implicit object CarFormat extends Format[Car] {

  implicit object DateFormat extends Format[java.util.Date] {
    val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
    def reads(json:JsValue): java.util.Date = format.parse(json.as[String])
    def writes(date:java.util.Date) = JsString(format.format(date))
  }

  def reads(json: JsValue): Car = Car(
    (json \ "id").as[Long],
    (json \ "height").as[Double],
    (json \ "weight").as[Double],
    (json \ "date").asOpt[java.util.Date]
  )   

  def writes(car: Car) = 
    JsObject(
        Seq(
            "id" -> JsString(car.id.toString),
            "height" -> JsString(car.height.toString),
            "weight" -> JsString(car.weight.toString),
            "date" -> JsString(car.date.toString)
        )   
    )   
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about late response since I could not find this inbox until now which is very stupid but I very thank you for your comment :)

Comment: @mythicalprogrammer in scala, you can put implicit definition anywhere, just bring it to scope where you need it.